# Turn existing entries on table into Hibernate entity objects

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I want to eliminate duplication in the data I receive (I turn the data into Objects (`Company.java`) and store them in table through Hibernate).

Whenever a new data comes in, I want to check it against all the entries through query.  In this case I am using the `uniquiResult()` method to check if data is already in the table.

Then, if the data doesn't exist already, create a new `Company` object with the data and save the `Company` object to the session.

However, if the data already exists, how do I grab the existing entry and turn it into an object?

My code is below:

```
            Company company;
            if(session
                    .createQuery("from company where company_name=:placeholder")
                    .setParameter("placeholder", data.getCompanyName())
                    .uniqueResult()
                    !=null){
                company = ????;
            } else {
                company = new Company(data.getCompanyName());
                session.save(company);
            }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Company company = session
                    .createQuery("from company where company_name=:placeholder")
                    .setParameter("placeholder", data.getCompanyName())
                    .uniqueResult();


if(company == null) {
    company = new Company(data.getCompanyName());
    session.save(company);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the documentation of Hibernate Session object

```
 Object uniqueResult() 
      Convenience method to return a single instance that matches the query, or null if the query returns no results.
```

i.e it executes your query, fetch the record from database and turn it into object for you.

The code you looking for is:

```
Company company = session.createQuery("from company where company_name=:placeholder")
                .setParameter("placeholder", data.getCompanyName())
                .uniqueResult()
                !=null;
if(company == null) {
  company = new Company(data.getCompanyName());
  session.save(company);
}
```